# How to get all items from subcollection Firebase Firestore Vue

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-composition-api

How do I get all the comments from the subcollection?

This is mine reusable function to get comments collection.

```js
    import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue';
    import { projectFirestore } from '../firebase/config';

    const getCollection = (collection, id, subcollection) => {
    const comments = ref(null);
    const error = ref(null);

    // register the firestore collection reference
     let collectionRef = projectFirestore
    .collection(collection)
    .doc(id)
    .collection(subcollection);

    const unsub = collectionRef.onSnapshot(
    snap => {
      let results = [];
      snap.docs.forEach(doc => {
        doc.data().createdAt && results.push(doc.data());
      });

      // update values
      comments.value = results;
      error.value = null;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err.message);
      comments.value = null;
      error.value = 'could not fetch the data';
    }
    );

    watchEffect(onInvalidate => {
      onInvalidate(() => unsub());
    });

       return { error, comments };
    };

    export default getCollection;
```

And this is mine Comments.vue where i passing arguments in setup() function (composition API)

```
const { comments } = getAllComments('posts', props.id, 'comments');
```

When i console.log(comments) its null, in snapshot doc.data() is good but somehow results too is empty array even if i push doc.data() to results array and pass it to comments.value.

Can someone help me how to get that subcollection?

This is my Comment.vue component

```
   export default {
    props: ['id'],
   setup(props) {
const { user } = getUser();
const content = ref('');

const { comments } = getAllComments('posts', props.id, 'comments');

const ownership = computed(() => {
  return (
    comments.value && user.value && user.value.uid == comments.value.userId
  );
});

console.log(comments.value);
}

return { user, content, handleComment, comments, ownership };
```

},
};

Comment: Where is `getAllComments()` defined?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i created composable folder for reusable functions (firebase functions) to get collection, post collection, get single document etc..

Comment: Can you update your question with complete code so we can see what that function does ?

Comment: @Dharmaraj this is what my function does, variable projectFirebase is firebase.firestore();
my function requires parameters and in Comments.vue i inport this file like import getAllComments.js from '@/composables/getAllComments' and in setup function
i destruction comments in const {comments} and call function with REAL parameters. i hope you understand me my english is bad, thank you

Comment: @PeterO. its works like that i get arrays with comments but in my Comment.vue when i log comment.value its null

Comment: @Dharmaraj Okay, I am not too familiar with Vue. Thanks.

Comment: Where  is your `console.log(comments.value)` statement? Where it is null.?

Comment: @Dharmaraj i set initially const comments  = ref(null) to fill data which I get from result variable in snapshot, i try to push doc.data() in result and then i pass that result in the comments.value = result

Comment: The problem is mostly because your log statement runs before the promise is resolved... unless you share your complete code which includes that `console.log(comments.value)` statement its hard to explain.

Comment: @Dharmaraj i updated and post comment.vue component

Comment: Check my answer, if you are having issues with null value then use an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const getCollection = (collection, id, subcollection) => {
  const comments = ref(null);
  const error = ref(null);

  // Firestore listener

  return { error, comments };
}
```

The initial value of `comments` here is null and since Firebase operations are asynchronous, it can take a while before the data loads and hence it'll log `null`. If you are using `comments` in `v-for` then that might throw an error.

It'll be best if you set initial value to an empty array so it'll not throw any error while the data loads:

```js
const comments = ref([]);
```

Additionally, if you are fetching once, use `.get()` instead of `onSnapshot()`